Power Consumption of STM32
I designed a PCB with STM32L0 series MCU. When I measured the power consumption of this PCB with Nordic PPK-II, it was consuming ~100uA. After that, I heat the STM32 with a hot air, and the power consumption drops to ~20uA.
Is it normal that power consumption decreases with increasing temperature? What is the reason of this?

Are you sure it is only measuring the STM32? Surely there are other things such as ceramic bypass caps right next to the STM32 on same supply pins?

I heat the STM32 with a hot air, and the power consumption drops to ~20uA. Maybe some internal modules stop working (over-temperature protection) and therefore stop drawing current. I don't know if SMT32 has such an over-temperature protection, though.

@Justme, Yes, there are many capacitors close to STM32. Do you think this change in power consumption is due to capacitors?

@RohatKılıç, The temperature I am talking about is not very high temperatures. As soon as I apply a temperature, the power consumption graph starts to decrease.

@harmonica It could be anything, unless ruled out what it isn't, and it's one of the things it still could be. Simply assuming it's the MCU without any thought is not a good start. The current of MCU should go up when heated.
